# What about $\int_0^1\frac{\log x}{\log(\gamma+\psi(x+1))}dx$, where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant and $\psi(x)$ the digamma function?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, reference-request, logarithms, digamma-function

I was reading the list of integrals from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_integrals), and I've created a variation of the integral $$\int \log_a(x)dx.$$
I show my example as a definite integral. I would like to know if is it possible to find an approximation of the integal of such *logarithm* in my example

$$\int_0^1\frac{\log x}{\log(\gamma+\psi(x+1))}dx,\tag{1}$$
where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant and $\psi(s)$ the digamma function.

> **Question.** How can we justify an approximation of $(1)$? Preferably using analysis and some asymptotic property of functions in the integrand. If this integral was in the literature and you need answer it as a reference request feel free to do it (then I am going to search and try understand such literaure). **Many thanks.**

See the integration that I've encoded and my integrand with [Wolfram Alpha online calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/)

`int log(x)/log(EulerGamma+Digamma(x+1))dx, from x=0 to 1`

`plot log(x)/log(EulerGamma+Digamma(x+1)), from x=0 to 1`

Comment: Why don't you take $\int_0^1 \frac{\log (x+1)}{\log (x+2)}\,dx$ ? Looking simple, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes I think that your example is good. Maybe was my blindness asking a more artificious question. Many thanks for your comment @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: Imagination and curiosity are very good qualities ! Continue that way. But, if I may, life is already difficult with even looking simple stuff. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

*This is not an answer to the question.*

Since I wrote it in a comment, let us consider something as simple as
$$I=\int_0^1 \frac{\log (x+1)}{\log (x+2)}\,dx$$ which, more than likely, does not show a closed form.

The numerical integration leads to $\approx \color{red} {0.402665}$.

To approximate the result, I used $[n,2]$ Padé approximants built around $x=0$ ; these are "easy" to obtain. For example, for $n=2$, we have
$$\frac{\log (x+1)}{\log (x+2)}=\frac{\frac{x}{\log (2)}+\frac{x^2}{2 \log (2)} } {1+x \left(1+\frac{1}{2 \log (2)}\right)+x^2 \left(\frac{1}{6}+\frac{3}{8 \log
   (2)}\right) }$$ Plot the two functions to see how close they are.

Integration does not make any problem and the result evaluates $\approx \color{red} {0.402}705$ which is not too bad.

Doing the same with $n=3$ would lead to  $\approx \color{red} {0.4026}52$.

Now, I give up !

Comment: Many thanks for your example. I presume that you are saying the Padé approximants showed, for example, from Wikipedia.

Comment: @user243301. I am a fantic user of Padé approximants (the Wikipedia page is good). They are so better than series ! I hope you liked this one. Cheers.

Comment: @user243301. I bet that making the expansion around $x=\frac 12$ would give better. It does ! for $n=2$, I get $\color{red} {0.40266}3$

Comment: Many thanks I read (the second paragraph of Wikipedia), about this  approximation by rational functions versus Taylor expansion.